# Location distance calculation getting wrong value

Tags: android, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am trying to tracking the user distance in meters but sometimes the distance given is much more than the user actually traveled. I think maybe is because of the curves or something like that but wonder what am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private LatLng mLastKnownLatLng;
    private float[] mResults = new float[]{0};
    private float mDistance = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        startLocationUpdates();
        createLocationCallback();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (checkLocationPermission())
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                Looper.myLooper());
    }

    private void createLocationCallback() {
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                if (mLastKnownLatLng == null)
                    mLastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                if ((mLastKnownLatLng.latitude != location.getLatitude()
                    && mLastKnownLatLng.longitude != location.getLongitude())
                    && location.getAccuracy() < 50) {

                    Location.distanceBetween(mLastKnownLatLng.latitude, mLastKnownLatLng.longitude,
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), mResults);

                    mDistance += mResults[0];

                    mLastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(latB);
locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

//in your case 

mLastKnownLatLng.distanceTo(location)
```

Comment: I already try this one, and also tried with `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(LatLngA, LatLngB)`. The results seems to be the same, so I think it's not the calculation itself but another bug that is giving me wrong information. I don't know.

Comment: I think, your  `mDistance += mResults[0];` gets updated multiple times. When are you checking the distance? How many times? and Do you want to reset it? Answer these questions for yourself and see if you can find out the issue.